# Drawing a sequence of circles

Tags: graphics, number-theory

For every natural number from 1 to 150, draw a circle centered on the x-axis in that number and with the diameter equal to the number of divisors of the number. I don't know what should I do.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Graphics[
 {r = Length[Divisors@#]/2;
    ColorData["Rainbow"][(r - 1)/7],
    Circle[{#, 0}, r]} & /@
  Range[150],
 ImageSize -> 504]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can get the radii using the built-in function [`DivisorSigma`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DivisorSigma.html) directly:

```
n = 150;
radii = DivisorSigma[0, Range @ n]/2;
```

Coloring the circles based on radius:

```
Graphics[MapThread[{Thick, ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, Max@radii}}]@#2, Circle[{#, 0}, #2]} &,
  {Range @ n, radii}]]
```

[image]

Coloring the circles based on the horizontal coordinate of the center:

```
Graphics[ MapThread[{Thick, ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, n}}]@#,  Circle[{#, 0}, #2]} &, 
  {Range @ n, radii}]]
```

[image]